# Tweaking the Tweet Follow Button

Tags: plugin-dukttwitter

Require a little help with removing the pre-parsed text from Dukt's `{{ twitterTweetButton() }}`

```
 <li><a href="  {{ twitterTweetButton({
                        text: "some text",
                        target: "_blank"
                    }) }}"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
```

This does not work....

The docs specify the following Twig functions:

- `text` — Pre-populated text highlighted in the Tweet composer.
- `url` — URL included with the Tweet.
- `hashtags` — A comma-separated list of hashtags to be appended to
  default Tweet text.
- `via` — Attribute the source of a Tweet to a Twitter username.
- `related` — A comma-separated list of accounts related to the content
  of the shared URI.
- `size` — Set to large to display a larger button.
- `lang` — A supported Twitter language code. Loads text components in
  the specified language. Note: does not affect the text of the cited
  Tweet.
- `dnt` — When set to true, the Tweet and its embedded page do not
  influence Twitter targeting including suggested accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the function currently does

```
public function tweetButton($options = [])
{
    $dataAttributes = $this->getOptionsAsDataAttributes($options);

    $html = '<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share"'.$dataAttributes.'>Tweet</a>';

    return $html;
}
```

So it returns an `a` tag rather than a link. You should remove your outer tag but you can't place your custom text. You would have to use a [string replace function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/replace.html)

```
{{ twitterTweetButton()|replace({'>Tweet<':' >my custom text<' }) }}
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, what I am trying to figure out is how to use these Twig functions (see above). The example I used to change the text for example, however I didn't get any results. PS: the string replacement doesn't work either...

Comment: Like I said, this won't do anything because the function does not work the way you want. As you can see there is no way to change the text. It's a hard coded string. You need to use the `replace` filter

Comment: The plugin's manual tells otherwise, thats all, however these instructions are related to Dukt's Craft 2 version. (see above) Thanks for your help, Robin.

Comment: Do you want to remove the "Tweet" string from the button or the text in the field? However it will still return a html element and no link

Comment: Thank you, Robin - I don't want to waste more of your time. I've dropped all Dukt's plugins and am working on a custom solution..